# Parsing PayPal SOAP response in C#

Tags: c#, xml, paypal

How do you parse this XML file?  I need to get Ack and Token values

I've tried

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument()
doc.LoadXml(xml)
XmlNode Ack = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//Ack")
XmlNode Token = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//Token")
```

My xml string is good as below, but Ack and Token are null.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:cc="urn:ebay:apis:CoreComponentTypes" xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/utility" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xmlns:ed="urn:ebay:apis:EnhancedDataTypes" xmlns:ebl="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" xmlns:ns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <Security xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xsi:type="wsse:SecurityType"></Security>
    <RequesterCredentials xmlns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI" xsi:type="ebl:CustomSecurityHeaderType">
      <Credentials xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" xsi:type="ebl:UserIdPasswordType">
        <Username xsi:type="xs:string"></Username>
        <Password xsi:type="xs:string"></Password>
        <Signature xsi:type="xs:string"></Signature>
        <Subject xsi:type="xs:string"></Subject>
      </Credentials>
    </RequesterCredentials>
  </SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body id="_0">
    <SetExpressCheckoutResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI">
      <Timestamp xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">2015-10-09T21:21:39Z</Timestamp>
      <Ack xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">Success</Ack>
      <CorrelationID xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">fsfsd8d6bb</CorrelationID>
      <Version xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">112</Version>
      <Build xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">18sdf778</Build>
      <Token xsi:type="ebl:ExpressCheckoutTokenType">EC-6YBsdfs24894B</Token>
    </SetExpressCheckoutResponse>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are interacting with soap services you might want to add a service reference and have it create proxy classes for you.

Using Linq to XML  you can do something like the below

```
    var parsedSoap = XElement.Parse(soapMessage);
    XNamespace  payPalResponseNs ="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI";
    XNamespace resultingResponseNs = "urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents";
    parsedSoap.Descendants()
              .Where(x=> x.Name == payPalResponseNs+"SetExpressCheckoutResponse")
              .Select(x=> new 
                    {
                        Timestamp = x.Element(resultingResponseNs +"Timestamp")?.Value,
                        Ack = x.Element(resultingResponseNs +"Ack")?.Value,
                        CorrelationID = x.Element(resultingResponseNs +"CorrelationID")?.Value,
                        Version = x.Element(resultingResponseNs +"Version")?.Value,
                        Build = x.Element(resultingResponseNs +"Build")?.Value,
                        Token = x.Element(payPalResponseNs +"Token")?.Value
                    }
                    );
```

Or Better yet

Answer (score 0):

```html
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlNamespaceManager mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
        mgr.AddNamespace("PayPalAPI", "urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI");
        mgr.AddNamespace("eBLBaseComponents", "urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents");
        doc.LoadXml(xml);
        XmlNode Ack = doc.SelectSingleNode("//eBLBaseComponents:Ack", mgr);
        XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("//PayPalAPI:SetExpressCheckoutResponse", mgr);
        
        string strAck = null;
        if (Ack != null)
            strAck = Ack.InnerText.ToLower();
        if (strAck != null && (strAck == "success" || strAck == "successwithwarning"))
        {
            //token = decoder["TOKEN"];
            foreach (XmlNode child in node.ChildNodes)
            {
                if (child.Name.ToLower() == "token")
                {
                    token = child.InnerText;
                }
            }
        }
```